# My container is only spread through half of the body. I want it to spread it full window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.square {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="square.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been trying to draw in CSS and every project I pick this issue pops up. I tried setting body margin and padding to 0, but this issue still occurs. If any of you could help that would be great.

Comment: it should be `width: 100vw`, not `width: 100vh`. in addition, single page application it's good to set `position: fixed`

Answer (score 1):

In class `container`, your width should be `width: 100vw`

`vh` is for viewport height and `vw` is for viewport width